# Export to XLSX where the page should also contain header

Tags: java, excel, grails, grails-plugin

I am using Grails and I am exporting a list of data to the excel sheet.Simple export of table is done, but I need header in that page which consists of a company's logo and the report's title. and the sheet must be saved according to the status of the data which should be in 5 sheets..Also page width must be 11in...

Requirement

- 5 Sheets:Open,....,closed
- Header:
  Left side: Logo,
  Right side:Report title

So can anyone suggest how to do this!!

Comment: have you tried Apache POI, http://poi.apache.org/ ? If so do let us know exactly what you have tried and what you have got working.

Comment: I am using plugin of grails (http://grails.org/plugin/export)   Using this plugin i got the tables in xls form but i need to add header to that page such as company logo and title of the report...Please suggest me in that

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `[header.enabled:true]` as one of the formatters?

Comment: refer the the documentation at http://grails.org/plugin/export . There is an example of adding formatters.